# Create AWS DC Proxy Target Group timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create a simple rds proxy. I use the attached cloudformation template. However aws cannot create resource "AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup". The error info is not enough for debugging: "Resource timed out waiting for completion". Please anyone provide me anwser?

Target group was created, but info was not updated in cloudformation event

[rds_proxy_console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwNZh.png)

[CF_event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgMgE.png)

[failed event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4Hb.png)

```
Resources:
  RDSProxy:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBProxy"
    Properties:
      Auth:
        - AuthScheme: SECRETS
          IAMAuth: DISABLED
          SecretArn: !Sub "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:${SecretsManagerName}"
      DBProxyName: !Ref ProxyName
      EngineFamily: !Ref ProxyEngineFamily
      RoleArn: !GetAtt SecretsManagerRole.Arn
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: !Ref ProxyVpcSecurityGroupIds
      VpcSubnetIds: !Ref ProxyVpcSubnetIds

  RDSProxyTargetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBProxyTargetGroup"
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifiers: !Ref ProxyTargetDBClusterIdentifiers
      DBProxyName: !Ref RDSProxy
      TargetGroupName: default
```

Comment: What are security groups settings for proxy and rds? Also are they in the same vpc?

Comment: @Marcin I use the same sg as lambda funtion. and yes, they are in the same VPC. The target group was created but cloudformation was not updated. After 2 hours, cloudofrmation rollbacked because of timeout

Comment: Which lambda function? I mean what are the inbout/output rules for SGs of the proxy and rds idb instance? Your code does not show any lambda function.

Comment: i seem to have the same problem. did you ever find a solution?

Comment: no, but I run the script yesterday , and it worked, nothing changed, you can try again, maybe it work this time